# Twit.js - How can i use the Twitter endpoint "friendship/create"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

)

For a while i have been trying to make use of the twit.js package to build myself a twitter bot. It seems to be working fine, but I still can't figure out how to "follow" other twitter accounts.

What i wan't is that when a twitter account is tweeting something about a topic then I want to be able to follow them / add friendship.

I still haven't found anything in the twit.js documentation about how I can add friendship / follow other twitter accounts, so I hope that some of You might know. I tried making a post request to the friendship/create endpoint, but i just get an answer back that the page doesn't exist or the user cannot be found both using user id and by screen_name.